# Interrupted system call in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals, system-calls

I want to make my program sleep upto 10 seconds even the signal is occured. So, I tried the following program.

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<errno.h>
int main()
{
    printf("PID: %d\n",getpid());
    int unslept=10;
    while(unslept>0){
        unslept=sleep(unslept);
        if(errno==EINTR)
            continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
PID: 18935
User defined signal 1
$
```

I expect the above program will execute 10 seconds even the signal is interrupted. I exeperiment it like, in one terminal I 
executed this program. And using another terminal using kill command I sent the SIGUSR1 signal to this process. But, the same problem
occurs. Once the signal is passed, the program terminates. So, is there any way to execute my program upto 10 seconds without affecting
any signal.

Comment: Do you want to handle these signals or just ignore them?

Comment: If you read [the `signal(7)` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) you will see that the default action for `SIGUSR1` (and `SIGUSR2`) is to terminate the process.

Comment: Please read an introduction on signals. It seems that you have problems understanding how singals work.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore the signal. See the below example, in that example, if the SIGUSR1 signal is interrupted, it just ignore the signal using the SIG_IGN.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>

    int main(void)
    {
            if (signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)
                    perror("SIGUSR1");

            sleep(30);
    }
```

Comment: Please remember that ignoring a signal causes system calls to stop being interrupted by the signal. If you want to “do nothing” on a signal but still be interrupted, register an empty signal handler instead.

Comment: I think that time it will handle the signal. that time also it will interrupted.

Comment: Yes, but when you ignore a signal, it isn't handled and your process is never interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use signal handling mechanism. Register your method that will handle interrupt signals and just ignore it that in your function.

```
// signal handler
    void my_function(int sig){
      //do nothing
    }

// register signal
    signal(SIGNAL_ID, my_function);
```